# React Firebase - retrieving photoURL from users collection to render in comments section

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, collections, user-profile

I have a React app with Firebase backend. I have a users collection in the database which stores the photoURL of the user.

When a user comments on a post, instead of saving that photoURL each time into the comments collection I just want to render the photoURL from the users collection.

That way if the user updates their photoURL it is updated on all the comments plus there's no duplication of data.

On each comment I have saved the uid in the comment collection. I just can't quite figure out how to map through all the comments and take the uid and use that to get the photoURL from the users collection. Below is what I have so far.

I'm new to React so apologies if this is a simple fix.

```
const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

// This is used to get all the comments
    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribe
        if (postId) {
            unsubscribe = db.collection('posts').doc(postId).collection('comments').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                setComments(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
            })
        }
        return () => {
            unsubscribe()
        }
    }, [postId])


// This is for adding the comment to the comments collection
const postComment = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        db.collection('posts').doc(postId).collection('comments').add({
            text: comment,
            username: user.displayName,
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            photoURL: user?.photoURL, // This does not save anything because it's taking form auth user and not user collection
            uid: user?.uid
        })
        setComment('')
        setCommentActive(true)
        setCommentsArrow(!commentsArrow)
    }


// This is a function to get the photoURL of any user based on the uid
async function getImageURL(uid) {
     return (await db.collection("users").doc(uid).get()).data().photoURL
}


// Rendering the comments
return (
<div style={{ transition: "height 0.3s linear" }} className={commentActive ? null : "hidden"}>
    <div className="post__comments">
                    
         {comments.map((comment) => (
              <div className="post__comment">
                   <Avatar
                        className="post__avatar"
                           alt=""
                           src={getImageURL(comment.uid)} // Calls the getImageURL function and passes in the uid from the comment
                    />
                    <p><strong>{comment.username}</strong> {comment.text}</p>
              </div>
          ))}
    </div>
</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 2 options that I see are viable:

1. I see you are storing the users' UID in the comment doc, then make a separate request to Firestore (users collection) and then fetch their photoURL from that document.
2. This is what I prefer and seems to be the most viable way but to do so you would have to store the user images in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) or any storage service. There you can structure your directory like `/images/<user_uid>`. So if my UID in the comment is 'uid123' then you would look for the image in Firebase Storage.

A download URL from Firebase Storage looks like:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<project_id>.appspot.com/o/users%2F<userId>.png?alt=media&token=token
```

Now it does has that token at the end so you may have to use the [getDownloadURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) method or make your bucket public from the Google Cloud Console. But the format of URL will remains consistent i.e. `https://domain.tld/path/image.png`

This means users can't just simply paste an image URL to update their photo but they'll have to upload the image and you'll have to store it somewhere.

If you don't want to use storage or the 2nd method above, then you would have to make additional calls to the database to get users' profile picture.

**Edit:**
Function to get user's image URL from UID:

```
async function getImageURL(uid) {
  return (await db.collection("users").doc(uid).get()).data().photoURL
}
```

Then in the component below:

```
{comments.map((comment) => (
    <div className="post__comment">
        <Avatar
            className="post__avatar"
            alt=""
            src={getImageURL(comment.uid)}
        />
        <p><strong>{comment.username}</strong> {comment.text}</p>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: Hello Dharmaraj, thanks for getting back to me. The first option was my original thought. My problem is I don't know how to write the code to take that uid from the comment document and use it to look up the photoURL from the user document. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @MarkMcClean you can read the property just like you are reading the text. comment.uid. You can create function fetchImageURL(uid) {...} and then make a query. Please refer updated code in my answer. If the answer was helpful you can accept/upvote it else feel free to ask further queries.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Unfortunately it's not working. I'm getting an error on the function - "Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path." Any further ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @MarkMcClean please share your updated code. Looks like you are not passing the UID correctly.

Comment: see edited code in the question with the additional async function added to get the user photoURL and the call of that function in the src of the Avatar.